# How to aggregate lookup sub array documents in mongoDB, and projecting the result?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 Collections

1. Posts
2. Users

**Posts** collection contains comments array which stores `{ userId, comment }` object, along with other information.

**users** ollection contains user's information.

I want to return the complete result.

Ex:

```
{
    "postId":"xvzeee",
    "post": "Good Morning",
    "likedBy":[ 
        12342234,
        23456534
    ]
    "comments": [
    {   
        "comment": "very good morning",
        "userName": "Max"
    },
    {
        "comment": "v. GM",
        "userName": "Suraj"
    }
    ]
}
```

My Approach to achieve the above result is.

```
db.wall.aggregate([
    { $lookup: { from: 'profiles', localField: 'likedBy', foreignField: 'profileId', as: 'likedBy' } },
    { $lookup: { from: 'profiles', localField: 'comments.commentedBy', foreignField: 'profileId', as: 'commentedUser' } },
    {
        $project:{ 
            "likedBy.name": 1,
            "likedBy.profileId": 1,
            createdBy: 1,
            createdAt: 1,
            updatedAt: 1,
            comments : [{
                comment: "$comments.comment",
                user: "$commentedUser.name"
            }],
            "commentedUser.name" : 1
        }
    }
])
```

The result is coming like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfdbb129f644213c413eb18"),
    "likedBy" : [
        {
            "profileId" : "96444206",
            "name" : "Vinay3"
        },
        {
            "profileId" : "400586806",
            "name" : "Dev"
        }
    ],
    "createdBy" : "96444206",
    "commentedUser" : [
        {
            "name" : "Vinay3"
        },
        {
            "name" : "Dev"
        }
    ],
         /*Facing problem in comment array*/
    "comments" : [
        {
            "comment" : [
                "Super-awesome",
                "FAB",
            ],
            "user" : [
                "Vinay3",
                "Dev"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The comment should look like :

```
[{
 ...
"comments" : [
        {
            "comments" : [
                { 
                   comment :"Super-awesome",
                   user: "Vinay3",
                   profileId: "11111..."
                },
                {
                   comment: "FAB",
                   user: "Dev",
                   profileId: "2222..."
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}]
```

The **Posts** Collection looks like this :

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dfdbb129f699913c413eb18"),
    "post":"Good Morning",
    "createdBy" : "96444206",
    "postId" : "D9644s5h8m",
    "likedBy" : [
        "96444206",
        "40058680"
    ],
    "comments" : [
        {
            "commentId" : "COM9644",
            "commentedBy" : "96444206",
            "comment" : "Super-awesome"
        },
        {
            "commentId" : "COM9644",
            "commentedBy" : "96444206",
            "comment" : "#FAB"
        },
        {
            "commentId" : "COM00587",
            "commentedBy" : "400586806",
            "comment" : "marvelous"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-12-21T11:56:26.944+05:30"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-12-21T12:12:35.047+05:30"),
    "__v" : 0
}, {...}, {...}]
```

**User Profiles Collection**

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5dd4ff3abe53181160efa446"),
    "accountStatus" : "CONFIRMED",
    "profileId" : "400586806",
    "name" : "Dev",
    "email" : "dev@xyz.com",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-11-20T14:24:18.692+05:30"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2019-12-20T16:58:06.041+05:30"),
    "__v" : 0
}, {...}, {...} ]
```

How to achieve this, any help will much be appreciated.

Comment: can you provide sample data of two collections?

Comment: I will update it in my question

Comment: this is only one collection data, what about other one, where you start $lookup in?

Answer (score 0):

However, I'm able to give a solution to my problem like below.

If there any better solution than this will much be appreciated.

```
db.wall.aggregate([
    { $unwind: '$comments'},
    { $lookup: { from: 'profiles', localField: 'comments.commentedBy', foreignField: 'profileId', as: 'comments.user' } },
    { $unwind: '$comments.user' },
    { 
        $group: {
            _id:'$_id',
            postId:  { $first: "$postId"},
            likedBy: { $first: "$likedBy"},
            createdBy: { $first: '$createdBy'},
            comments: { $push : '$comments' },
            createdAt: { $first: "$createdAt" },
            updatedAt: { $first: "$updatedAt" },
        }
    },{
        $project: { 
            _id:1,
            postId: 1,
            "likedBy.name": 1,
            "likedBy.profileId": 1,
            createdBy: 1,
            comments: { 
                $map : {
                    input: '$comments',
                    as: 'com',
                    in: {
                        commentId: "$$com.commentId",
                        comment: "$$com.comment",
                        name: "$$com.user.name"
                    }
                }
            },
            createdAt: 1,
            updatedAt: 1,
        }
    }
])
```

I want to add `isActive => true || false` field to the comments object. 
now the challenge is how to filter only `isActive => true` comments ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach

```
db.posts.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: '$likedBy',
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$comments',
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'likedBy',
            foreignField: 'profileId',
            as: 'likedByUser'
        },
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$likedByUser'
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'comments.commentedBy',
            foreignField: 'profileId',
            as: 'commentByUser'
        },
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$commentByUser'
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": '$postId',
            "post": { $first: 'post'} ,
            comments: {
                $push: {
                    "commentId": "$comments.commentId",
                    "commentedBy": "$likedByUser.name",
                    "comment": "$comments.comment"
                }
            },
            likes: {
                 $push: {
                    "likedByName": "$likedByUser.name",
                    "likeById": "$likedBy"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": 0,
            "postId":'$_id',
            "post": 1,
            "comments": 1,
            "likes": 1
        }
    }
])
```